# how to add next and previous link on content full display page on tpl file in drupal 7?

Tags: theming

[image]I have a content type called flower and I have created a node--flower.tpl.php for displaying products.

I am also using category of flowers. I need to add next and previous links on this page for a specific category. For example if I'm on rose page then all roses are needed to show on next and previous link, not other category data.

Comment: How do you want to decide which node is "Next" and which is "Previous"? For example it could maybe be by modified date, node ID, menu order, etc.

Comment: modified date.. but all node should same category..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write this logic yourself in a `hook_preprocess_node()`. This code should be added to the `template.php` file of your front end theme.

Here's an example:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // Perform the logic for selecting prev/next terms here. Install and use
  // the Devel module to see what is available to you and to debug the code.

  // See what's available:
  dpm($variables);

  // Load a sample term. Note: this should be different if your website is
  // in multiple languages. Below is just an example.
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($variables['node']->field_term[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid']);

  // Pass a variable to the node--flower.tpl.php file. Code below will make
  // the $previous_category and $next_category variables available in the
  // node--flower.tpl.php file.
  $variables['previous_category'] = 'Your link here';
  $variables['next_category'] = 'Your link here';
}
```

Comment: I need to next and previous functionality for node not a term . can is it possible?

Comment: Yep. Use the above code and add your logic. If you explain what exactly do you mean by "next node" I might be able to help as well :)

Comment: I have attached image above please check.

Comment: Please let me know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the previous and next node with a specific category? I'm not pretty sure but looks like in this case you have to do something like this in your node template

**(i haven't tasted it)**

```
$prev_nid = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {term_node} WHERE nid < :nid AND tid = TID ORDER BY nid DESC LIMIT 1", array(':nid' => $node->nid, ':tid' => $node->TAXONOMY_FIELD['und'][0]['tid']))->fetchField();

$next_nid = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {term_node} WHERE nid > :nid AND tid = TID ORDER BY nid LIMIT 1", array(':nid' => $node->nid, ':tid' => $node->TAXONOMY_FIELD['und'][0]['tid']))->fetchField();


if (@$prev_nid > 0) {@$prev_link = l('Previous', "node/$prev_nid");}
if (@$next_nid > 0) {@$next_link = l('Next', "node/$next_nid");}

print @$prev_link . ' - ' .@$next_link;
```

Comment: you have a couple of typos - :tid isn't in the query but is defined in the list of placeholders, and what would it taste like if you had? :)